# Rails 5.1 run system tests and normal tests with one command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

In Rails 5.1, you can do `bin/rails test` to run normal tests, and `bin/rails test:system`. What is the Rails sanctioned way of running both at the same time?

Comment: I am not sure but can you try using `bin/rails test test:system`? It should load Rails' env and your app only once.

Comment: Sadly didn't work; just ran the normal suite, not system tests.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`bin/rails test:system test`

Specifying `test:system` before `test` will run both system and ordinary tests. The opposite order will only run the ordinary tests however.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I've been using `simplecov` to verify my test coverage and this command really helps. `rails test` gets me 54.96%. 'rails test:system' gets me 42.82%, but `rails test:system test` runs both and gets me 78.64% coverage, so I can see the overlap.

Answer (score 17):

### `rails test:all` (Rails 6.1+)

Rails 6.1 introduces a new command - `rails test:all`.

It runs all test files in the test directory, including system tests.

Here is a [link to PR](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/39221).
And also a [link to the docs](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#implementing-a-system-test) (please, scroll down to yellow box).

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone else is looking for the answer:

`bin/rails test test/*`

Answer (score 2):

If it is your intention to run it using just `$ rake` or `$rake test` you can add into your Rakefile:

```
task test: 'test:system'
```

This will makes 'test:system' a "prerequisites" for "test" task

Answer (score 1):

At least from the official rails guide, it seems there is no way of doing it:

> By default, running bin/rails test won't run your system tests. Make sure to run bin/rails test:system to actually run them.

Ref: [rails guide](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#implementing-a-system-test)

Answer (score 0):

You can also add this snippet in your lib/tasks folder, that will give you the option to do `rake test:all`

`namespace :test do
  desc "Run both regular tests and system tests"
  task :all => 'test' do
    Minitest.after_run {system('rake test:system')}
  end
end`

Answer (score 0):

Summary of all the answers for easy reference:

#### System tests Only

`bin/rails test:system`

#### Ordinary tests Only

`bin/rails test .`

#### ALL tests

`bin/rails test:all`